# app crashes when intent passes variable to another activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

i am making a app that tracks the user and tracks another user which in theory would be an animal.
my app goes like this, you register a username and pass then when this is done the user can log into the map by reentering the correct username and password. This is where the issues begin.
upon creation of the screen the map loads with the users current location and auto sends a sms to the "animals" phone to request gps details, this then sends back 2 sms messages, 1 containing the gps information. i have a SmsReceiver class which reads this information and extracts the longitude and latitude data, converts it into a double then passes it to the map activity to be converted into a lnglat variable and displayed on the google map with a marker. Now the issue i am having is that it can take several minutes for the sms to return with the gps information, when this is done and the intent is used to send the coordinates to the map page a button must be clicked so that the longitude and latitude are combined into the AnimalCoordinate and the marker is shown, however because og the time gap its imposible to press the button at the same time the sms is retrieved and it causes a crash as the data is being sent from the smsreceiver class to nothing on the other side, and if i take the intent out of the onclick method the same thing happens but in reverse, the map runs the intent but the informaion is not there yet and it crashes.
any help would be greatly appreciated as this has been a nightmare.

i am also sorry if i overcomplicated the explanation, i wanted to ake sure it was explained as best i could.
the code is below for the two classes.

```
Map class

public class MainScreen extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener {
private GoogleMap map;
private LocationManager locationManager;
private String provider;
final Context context = this;



   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);
    map = ((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().
    findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

    LocationManager service = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    boolean enabledGPS = service
            .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    boolean enabledWiFi = service
            .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

    // Check if enabled and if not send user to the GSP settings
    if (!enabledGPS) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "GPS signal not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    // Define the criteria how to select the locatioin provider -> use
    // default
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    // Initialize the location fields
    if (location != null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Selected Provider " + provider,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        onLocationChanged(location);
    } else {

        //do something
    }
    // Sets the map type to be "hybrid"
    map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();


    double lat =  location.getLatitude();
    double lng = location.getLongitude();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Location " + lat+","+lng,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    LatLng Usercoordinate = new LatLng(lat, lng);
    Marker User = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(Usercoordinate)
    .title("You are here")
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));
    //Move the camera instantly to user with a zoom of 15.
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(Usercoordinate, 15));

    // Zoom in, animating the camera.
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(18), 2000, null);

    //Sends sms to 'animal phone'
      String phoneNo = "***********";
      String sms = "GPSLocation";

      try {
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, sms, null, null);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Sent!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "SMS faild, please try again later!",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
      }

    }

public void map_help(View view) {
    //method for the help button

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            context);

        // set title
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Help");

        // set dialog message
        alertDialogBuilder
     .setMessage("Click the 'Pet' button to display the pets location." +
                    "This can take a few minutes to retrieve.")
            .setCancelable(false)
    .setPositiveButton("ok",new   DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id)        {
                    // if this button is clicked, close
                    // current activity
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
              });
            // create alert dialog
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                // show it
                alertDialog.show();
                                };

public void Find_Pet(View view)
{

      //String phoneNo = "07516909014";
     // String sms = "GPSLocation";

     // try {
    //  SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        //smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, sms, null, null);
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Sent!",
            //      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//    } catch (Exception e) {
    //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
        //  "SMS faild, please try again later!",
            //Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    //  e.printStackTrace();
      //}
}

public void Show_Pet(View view)
{
    //gets coordinates from SmsReceiver
    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    double AnimalLat = b.getDouble("key");

    Bundle d = getIntent().getExtras();
    double AnimalLon = d.getDouble("key1");

    LatLng Animalcoordinate = new LatLng(AnimalLat, AnimalLon);
    //adds pets marker on map
    Marker Animal = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(Animalcoordinate)
    .title("Your pet is here")
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));
}


/* Request updates at startup */
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);
}

/* Remove the locationlistener updates when Activity is paused */
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {


}


@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Enabled new provider " + provider,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}


@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Disabled provider " + provider,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}


@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

SmsReceiver class

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
String lat = null;
String lon = null;
String message = null;
final SmsReceiver context = this;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{
    //---get the SMS message passed in---
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
    SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
    String str = "";            
    if (bundle != null)
    {
        //---retrieve the SMS message received---
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];            
        for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                
            str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();

        }}

            message = str.toString();
            String[] test = message.split("");
            char[] test2 = test[1].toCharArray(); 
            //if the first character of the sms is C then read gps information
            if (test2[0] == 'C' || test2[0] =='c')
            {
            lat = message.substring(45, 56);
            lon = message.substring(67, 78);

            double AnimalLat=Double.parseDouble(lat);
            double AnimalLon=Double.parseDouble(lon);

            //Pass coordinates to MainScreen
            Intent a = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainScreen.class);
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putDouble("key", AnimalLat);
            a.putExtras(b);
            startActivity(a);

            Intent c = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainScreen.class);
            Bundle d = new Bundle();
            d.putDouble("key1", AnimalLon);
            c.putExtras(d);
            startActivity(c);

            }else {
            }       

   }

private void startActivity(Intent a) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

private Context getApplicationContext() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}}
```

I also want to apologize for the layout of the code, this is the first time i have pasted code on this site.
Thanks again.

Comment: That is a lot to look at but can't you just disable the `Button` until whatever object is `null`? Or you can have it enabled but don't run the code if the data is `null`. Also, other than there being a lot of it, the code is formatted fine

Comment: @codeMagic hmm i didnt think of that, to be honest i didnt think i could do that lol..so it would be something like if Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    double AnimalLat = b.getDouble("key");

    Bundle d = getIntent().getExtras();
    double AnimalLon = d.getDouble("key1");

Comment: @codeMagic sorry didnt mean to press enter aha so code would be similar to if bundle b and budnle d == null {do nothing}?  also if so make you comment an answer encase it works so i can mark it as one :)

Comment: Yeah, something like that. Let me know if it works and I will put as an answer

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I'm not sure which `Button` you are talking. The only one I saw was in the `AlertDialog` unless I missed something. Anyway, you can disable your `Button` until whatever data has a value or you can do nothing in the `onClick()` if it is `null`

```
//inside your Button
if (data != null)
{
     ...do stuff in here
}
```

If you need more clarification then please indicate in the code the data you are talking about and the `Button` but I think you get the idea.

Comment: ahh sorry in the code the button isnt there, the bundle is outside it however i tried it inside a button aswel, ill give that a go now and get back to you, thanks

Comment: Ok, if the `bundle` is declared outside of the `onClick()` listener then I believe you will have to declare it as `final` but inside should work. If you still have problems edit your post to put the `bundle` and `onClick()` code together so I can have a better understanding of how you are doing it. Let me know how it goes

Comment: i forgot to say it wont work, the intent cannot be inside a button as the intent in SmsReceiver sends the data to MainScreen and because the intent is inside the button it crashes uless the user maages to press button on time which is unlikly. the issue is i need the receiving intent in the oncreate method or someother on method that will work if possible as the SmsReeiver can take up to 5 mins for the sms to be receiver and converted. but because the intetn is in oncreate and has no information in it when the map is loaded(which hapens at the same time the sms is first sent) therefor crashing

Comment: im sorry its a bit hard to explain aha

Comment: basicly the only issue is the declaring the variables  double AnimalLat=Double.parseDouble(lat); and double AnimalLon=Double.parseDouble(lon); or if i covert them to LatLng Animalcoordinate = new LatLng(AnimalLat, AnimalLon); then that would mean only one variable would be needed in the MainScreen but i couldnt get it to work with it.

Comment: Ok, what is the issue with declaring them? Not being able to use them in `onClick()`? If so, then declare them as `final`. I will try to look closer in a little bit if that doesn't solve your problem

Comment: sorry im stressed and not thinking right now aha, i mean getting the variable from the smsreveiver class to mainscreen, but because of the flow of the app either the intent sends and the intent is not there to receive or the receive intent is there but nothing was sent

Comment: its ery frustrating as this is the last part of the app and if i cant get it working the main functionality does not, in theory it should be as simple as declaring the variabl as global(if possible) and calling it in the main screen with the data in it from sms receiver